# How to avoid my application in complete action dialog in android?

Tags: android

when I am using some third party application in device, I am getting two options like application name, my current using application.

Like Complete action using 1)third party app which I called

```
                        2) my current running application
```

How to avoid my current application in this (Complete action using)  Dialog?

Thanks

Comment: what's a "third party application in device"?

Comment: Barcode application (Zxing)

Comment: are you starting an intent from your application or are you opening some resource? if you don't want your application in this list don't register it with intent filter.

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(
        "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");

Comment: startActivityForResult(intent, 0); this is how I am using

Answer (score 0):

There is small check box whenever that dialog appears. Just tick on it

Comment: no,I want only the particular barcode application to be used.I dont want my application to be there in that Complete action Dialog box.

Comment: That is not possible to in unrooted device, you need to make your device root. Then only there will be some way to do it.

Comment: can you help me how can I do that